# Mean and variance of gray level for an image set per pixel

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, mean, standard-deviation

I have 10 gray images of the same size. I would like to obtain the mean gray value and standard deviation per pixel in the image set. How can I do this?

Comment: We won't do your work for you. Attempt the problem, then return and update your question if you run into a _specific_ problem

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your images are stored in a `XxYxN uint16` array called `imgs`:

```
X = 300; Y = 400; N = 10;
imgs = randi(2^16,Y,X,N,'uint16');
```

All you need to do is pass this matrix to `mean` and `std`, while specifying that you want to operate along the 3<sup>rd</sup> dimension:

```
meanMap = mean(imgs,3,'double');
stdMap = std(double(imgs),0,3);
```

Comment: And you have 10 of them right? And how are they stored? Let's assume `img1`, `img2` etc. So do `imgs = cat(3,img1,img2,....)`.

Comment: I can write the code so

X = 300; Y = 400; 
imgs = randi(2^16,Y,X,'uint8');

Comment: and .......meanMap = mean(imgs,2,'double');
stdMap = std(double(imgs),0,2);

Comment: The 10 image are already stored on pc .. I lesse from matlab and should I for each image the gray mean and the standard deviation for each pixel and I should create a diagram of average to standard deviation for everything 10 images

Comment: Please help me Thank you

Comment: I already helped with your original question (which was very broad to begin with). What you're asking now would be a **[different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not quite welcome")**, which you should post separately.